# how to validate username and password valid or not in login control using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one login control in my asp.net web application. I use the following code.

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" Width="351px" CssClass="login"
         FailureText="User Name/Password is incorrect"  
         EnableTheming="true" TitleText="Login into Focus/Career Status Viewer"  
         Height="164px" onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" DisplayRememberMe="False" 
             UserNameLabelText="Username:" >
        <TextBoxStyle  CssClass="login-textbox" />
        <LoginButtonStyle  CssClass="login-button" />
        <ValidatorTextStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
        <TitleTextStyle  CssClass="login-title"/>
    </asp:Login>
```

I want when i type username alone the error message will be produced like password required. Can anyone tell how can I do this??
Thankx in advance......

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Required Field Validator.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Password Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Hope this will help if u r using your own login control for login purpose

Comment: But i am not use my own login control. I use the asp.net login control. Can you please tell How can i validate that.

Comment: You can achieve the functionality you want by adding code on Login panel authenticate event. If Login1.Password is null then return with error,mention password is required. hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Although the login control is tempting, it is often a much more dynamic approach to create your own login control. Basically a table with two labels, two textboxes and one button. Then you can implement the suggestion from Saad with the validation controls. You will also have much more control with theming and with error handling IMHO. If you are determined to follow the login control route you may need to look at the templates for it but it has been a while since i looked into it